# Accessible Android Reader Application for text, epub, daisy and PDF formats

Tags: external-keyboard, ebook-reader, accessibility, talk-back

I need to find applications for particular formats of books:
1) ePub - Cool Reader, Ideal
2) Daisy - Darwin Reader
3) Txt - Accessible Talkback Editor
4) PDF- Adobe Reader, Smart Q Reader

Requirement:
Application with Reading Granularity Support for blind or low vision users from external keyboard-  Page, Sentence, Word and Sentence level selection of text while reading.

Problem:
There is no app which is clear or has documented the external keyboard usage for blinds or low vision users, except Accessible Talkback Editor none on the app has a clear UI/Documentation to suggest the Granularity selection.

Comment: What is "Reading Granularity Support"? I tried Googling the term and nothing related to blind or low vision support showed up (other than this question).

Comment: Its forcing the TalkBack to read as per Page, Sentence, Word or Alphabet level and stop after reading that part.